# Grunt build for production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have two grunt configurations as shown below

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy','jade','sass','browserify']);
grunt.registerTask('dev',['copy','jade','sass','browserify','watch']);
```

Now because i am using `grunt-contrib-watch`, i need to add script below

```
script(src='//localhost:35729/livereload.js')
```

for live-reload to work. How can i optionally add the script based on production environment. Having two `index.jade` file is a option and that gets me through this part, but there are a lot of other variables like api root etc that depends on build environment. What is the best practice in this case to build for production and dev environment ?

### Edit

Just to be sure. the above `index.jade` was just an example.Consider the following line in js code

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:3000");
```

The parameter needs to be separate for both dev and production. It would be totally illogical to have two copies of code for production and dev.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use params like `--build`

index.jade

```
if env.debug
  script(src='//localhost:35729/livereload.js')
```

Gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var DEBUG = grunt.option('build') === 'dev';

  // Configure Jade to conditionally render livereload.js
  // with DEBUG === true

  grunt.initConfig({
    pug: {
      options: {
        data: function() {
          return {
            env: {
              debug: DEBUG
            }
          };
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Use it like

```
grunt dev --build=dev
```

You can pass any env specific data via Grunt

```
grunt --build=dev \
      --api-endpoint=/api/foo
```

Comment: Thats for the grunt part. I already have two grunt scripts to distinguish between production and build. The problem is how to pass those variables into the JS file being compiled in browserify. Also the `--debug` flag only shows the verbose output from the build.

Comment: You are getting me wrong. I already know the build environment inside grunt file. Also i can conditionally build index.jade although that would be inefficient to have two files. The main problem is the angular code. You see in `dev` we have separate api endpoint as in `production`. There can't be two files for each code that way. Need someway to pass environment from grunt to the input for `browserify`

Comment: I didn't work with browserify, but for my webpack config i have modify config by pushing `DefinePlugin`, that switches dev/prod